# Heroku rollback and pulling older release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rollback

I did a mistake in the code and pushed it in to heroku master.  I am not able to identify the problem in the code I have locally. I did a `heroku rollback` to previous version - it worked and previous version is visible on heroku.

However I am struggling to pull the code (as `heroku clone:app name` gives me an old code). I tried `heroku releases` to get the release number which I then used for `git pull heroku af5c366b`, however getting err:

> fatal: Couldn't find remote ref af5c366b

How can the code be restored?

I am completely now to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply run...

`$ git checkout af5c366b`

Which should bring you to a "detached head" state with this helpful message..

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

Once you checkout the branch you can merge that branch into master.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge new-branch-name
```